# Plone ckeditor disable browse server

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, plone

I am using Plone 4.1 an ckeditor 3.6.2.
I disabled image and flash upload (via @@ckeditor-controlpanel)

Unfortuantely there is a "Browse Server" Button when I add a hyperlink.

I added empty properties (under portal-properties)

```
filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl
filebrowserBrowseUrl
```

nothing happend.

How can i disable this button?

regards,
saromba

Answer (score 0):

After long time I have the solution.
I override the CKeditorView class. I added in "my" configure.zcml:

```
<!-- ckeditor config view (return a javascript file) -->
<browser:page
    name="ckeditor_plone_config.js"
    for="zope.interface.Interface"
    class=".ckeditorview.CKeditorView"
    attribute="getCK_plone_config"
    permission="zope.Public"
    />
```

add a new file ckeditorview.py with this content:

```
from collective.ckeditor.browser.ckeditorview import CKeditorView as BaseView

class CKeditorView(BaseView):
    """
    CKeditor overrides
    """

    def getCK_plone_config(self):
        res = super(CKeditorView, self).getCK_plone_config()
        return res

    @property
    def cke_params(self):
        """
        return CKEditor widget Settings
        """
        params = super(CKeditorView, self).cke_params
        params['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = "''"
        params['filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'] = "''"
        params['filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl'] = "''"

        return params
```